# .htaccess protect folder without username

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to protect a folder with .htaccess by asking just a password?

I don't want a username.

Answer (score 15):

HTTP auth will always ask for a username and password, and not just a password. The server doesn't generate the form that pops up, your browser does. And that form will always have a username and password. You can't tell it to only ask for a password.

But what you can do is generate an htpasswd file with a blank username so when the login window opens, people only need to enter a password and can leave the username field blank.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass the dialog box by using the URL? So far providing "empty" username doesn't work when using `http://username:password@adress:port`.