# How to pre-fill user field on protected directory

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

I plan to make a test subdomain on my website, protected by a password (.htaccess / .htpasswd). I only require minimal security and wish to make login easy for visitors who know the password. Can I arrange for the username field of the login box to be filled in with "visitor" or something suitable, so that my visitor only needs to type the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need username **and** password for HTTP basic auth, you can generate an .htpasswd file with a blank username so when the login window opens, people only need to enter a password and can leave the username field blank.

Or you can handle the HTTP basic auth yourself, without a .htaccess, and only require a username.

See also [.htaccess protect folder without username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112917/htacess-protection-folder-without-username)

In the RFC 2617 (HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication) I don't see any [response header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.2.1), that would allow you to send a preset username.